# power bi embedded - stuck

Tags: sql, reactjs, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

does anyone know for sure:

1. If I already have an application registered in azure, and i'm just adding the embedding now, do I need to register another app somewhere like it shows here:  https://app.powerbi.com/embedsetup/AppOwnsData
2. this code doesn't show any way for appownsdata. https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/React-TS/Embed%20for%20your%20organization/UserOwnsData/src/App.tsx
3. would localhost need to authenticate differently than production
4. how do I find my embed url

***UPDATE**** THE CURRENT ANSWER ISN'T REALLY WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR.  WHILE IT WAS NICE TO GET A Proof Of Concept Working IT'S NOT WHAT I NEED BECAUSE IT DOESN'T WORK FOR A MASTER USER.

Comment: any help for any of the bullets above would be amazing!

Comment: Unsure if you got this sorted, but I did a similar project.
1. Yes, register another app for your appownsdata.
2. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core
3. Yes, if you're in Azure, your app will need to use authentication. When you run it locally, your local security is used, which is different.
4. See the link for #2, you won't use an embed URL, but workspaceId and reportId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On power bi , on the **File menu**, select **Embed report > Website or portal**.

and then In the **Secure embed code dialog**, select the link you can use to embed this content, or the HTML you can paste into your blog or website in an iFrame.
[image]

Comment: but how can I make this secure?  Meaning, obviously doesn't sound safe to put this right in my client side page??

Comment: The Embed option doesn't automatically permit users to view the report. View permissions are set in the Power BI service.

Comment: will I need to have extra licenses for this?

Comment: I was originally trying to use master user.  is this using service principal?

Comment: one moment will provide you with a link to have all the info you need

Comment: here you go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure

Comment: but I do not see how this can work for master user?  Can it?  I don't want users to feel like they are logging in.  I want that to happen seamlessly behind the seens

Comment: also, I'm using appownsdata solution

Comment: you have generate an Embed Token for the reports, dashboards that you want to embed by calling the Power BI REST API Embed Token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243821/discussion-between-lizi-and-charfeddine-mohamed-ali).